How to copy vcpkg installed dlls using cmake install()
I've added vcpkg to my CMake project, and everything builds fine, but I would like the vcpkg installed dependencies to be added to my install directory.
My project consists of a core library, a wrapper dll, and an exe which is used to test the dll interface. In the core library I (am trying to) use a vcpkg, libdatachannel.
I have a root CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(MyProject)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -fPIC")
add_subdirectory(src)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(test)

Then in the src directory, CMakeLists.txt:
add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(api)
add_subdirectory(runner)

In the core directory, CMakeLists.txt:
find_package(libdatachannel CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(core STATIC <various files...>)
target_link_libraries(core PRIVATE LibDataChannel::LibDataChannel)

This is where I use the libdatachannel package.
In the api directory CMakeLists.txt:
set(MY_LIB mylib)
add_library(${MY_LIB} SHARED api.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${MY_LIB} core)
install(CODE [[
    file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
        LIBRARIES ${MY_LIB}
        )
    ]])
install(TARGETS ${MY_LIB}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

This is where I am trying to use GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES to copy the libdatachannel dll to the install directory.
In the runner directory, CMakeLists.txt:
set(APP_EXE runner)
add_executable(${APP_EXE} runner.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${APP_EXE} mylib)
install(TARGETS ${APP_EXE} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

This is the exe I'm trying to install.
When I install then run the runner.exe I get an error saying "datachannel.dll" was not found:

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

The command file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES) returns a list of dependent libraries. Since you run that command during installing, you should write more installation code for iterate over the that list and copy every library into the desired location. Note also, that installation code doesn't see targets and variables created in the "main" CMake code. So you need to generate that code by using values of those variables and target's properties. For more detailed info see duplicate questoin and its answers.
